# How to align the inputs with multiline error in bottom-aligned form?

Tags: css, forms, flexbox, css-grid, vertical-alignment

I have a form with the bottom-aligned behaviour, I need all the inputs in a row to be aligned to the bottom and be on one line visually. The reason for this is that the label can include instructions or not include them. The controls can be of different hight and type (text input, select, radio group, checkbox group, fieldset).
The form that is used is antd Form component that is build using flex, that's why the markup of input's and label's wrappers cannot be changed. Also the each ant class have it's own styles:

I use the `align-self: end;`to make the control div to be aligned to the bottom. It works fine when I have one-line error
But it doesn't look good when I have multi-line error.

Can anyone suggest how to align the controls properly using the CSS (maybe grid...)?

The desired result (the right input is located one the same line as the left one):

[image]

Thank you!

https://codepen.io/Ke1sy/pen/gOELweY

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="ant-form ant-form-vertical ant-form-align-fields-bottom">
    <div class="ant-row">
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
              <div>Label </div>
              <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">Label</div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Short instructions</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The styles that are applied over the antd styles:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 900px;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.ant-form-item {
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
}

.ant-form-item-label {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.ant-form-item-control {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ant-form-align-fields-bottom {
  .ant-form-item {
    height: 100%;
    .ant-form-item-row {
      height: 100%;
      display: grid;
      .ant-form-item-control {
        align-self: end;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Antd css file to include: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.24.15/antd.compact.min.css

Comment: Because of the complexity of your requirements (fluid height above and below the input), flexbox probably isn't ideal. You might look at CSS grid, which is two-dimensional (whereas flexbox is one-dimensional). Rows continue across columns, so you can maintain alignment.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you for recommendation, I will take into account it. I was trying to find a css grid solution for it, but I don't have enough experience in it. It would be great if you can share some ideas how to implement that using grid.

Comment: I won't be able to refactor your layout today. Here's a good resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid

Comment: Try adding `height: 100%;` to the `.ant-form-item-control` class, and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your html, you can apply `.form-item { grid-template-rows:subgrid; }`. Here is a simple example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
}

.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px 0
}

.form-item {
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.label {
  background: orange;
}

.control {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-item">
    <div class="label">
      <div>Label </div>
      <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong instructions Long instructions Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong instructions Long instruction </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="error">Short error</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
      <div class="error">errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong er</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**Using your provided html code:**

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px 0
}

.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col{
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:subgrid;
  grid-row:span 2;
  width:auto;
  max-width:unset;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item,
.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item>.ant-form-item-row{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:subgrid;
    grid-row:span 2;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item{
    margin:0;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row .ant-form-item-label {
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

.control {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.24.15/antd.compact.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="ant-form ant-form-vertical ant-form-align-fields-bottom">
    <div class="ant-row">
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
              <div>Label </div>
              <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">Label</div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Short instructions</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You don't mention in your question that you have no control over the grid markup. Just understand that there is either css grid or javascript. So if this form, let's say, comes with a backend, then you probably know exactly which columns are all defined. If you can set this in a variable for `grid-template-columns` and add variable styles similar to the `.ant-col` style.

And, yes, it will be a difficult decision, and maybe even a crazy one...

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row{
  display: grid;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .ant-form>.ant-row{
    --lg-8:33%;
    --lg-6:25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .ant-form>.ant-row{
    --md-8:33%;
    --md-6:25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .ant-form>.ant-row{
    --sm-6:50%;
    --sm-6:50%;
  }
}

.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px 0
}

.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col{
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:subgrid;
  grid-row:span 2;
  width:auto;
  max-width:unset;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item,
.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item>.ant-form-item-row{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:subgrid;
    grid-row:span 2;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row>.ant-col>.ant-form-item{
    margin:0;
}

.ant-form>.ant-row .ant-form-item-label {
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

.control {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.ant-form input{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.24.15/antd.compact.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="ant-form ant-form-vertical ant-form-align-fields-bottom">
    <div class="ant-row" style="grid-template-columns:var(--lg-8, var(--md-8, var(--sm-6))) var(--lg-6, var(--md-6, var(--sm-6)));">
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-lg-8 ant-col-md-8 ant-col-sm-6">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
              <div>Label </div>
              <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-lg-6 ant-col-md-6 ant-col-sm-6">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">Label</div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Short instructions</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for simple markup, but not for my case as I use antd form and grid inside I have a lot of additional wrappers, so applying styles to form won't work.

Comment: I have given you an idea how it can be done. You just need to transfer it to your html. If this is difficult for you, then I have supplemented the answer using the html code you provided.

Comment: If it was easy, I wouldn't have asked the question on stackoverflow. As I mentioned in several other solutions, I don't control the grid markup that user provides into my Form Component, so cannot manually set up the grid columns, and override the responsive styles for ant-cols `ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8` that are responsible for the columns width.

Comment: You don't mention in your question that you have no control over the grid markup. Just understand that there is either css grid or javascript. So if this form, let's say, comes with a backend, then you probably know exactly which columns are all defined. If you can set this in a variable for grid-template-columns and add variable styles similar to the .ant-col style. I added this comment to the answer, and made an example. I hope this helps you. With best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of your layout or other requirements you could use css-grid in order to get your desired layout.

If you remove the divs around each input and label, you could just use a grid, which flows in the column direction. The height of the rows will be defined by the largest item and therefore affect the other control-divs as well.

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.label {
  background: orange;
}

.control {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <form class="form">
    <div class="label">
      <div>Label</div>
      <div style="color: grey">
            Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong instructions
            Long instructions Long instructionsLong instructionsLong
            instructionsLong instructions Long instruction sjhdjsdhdjshdsj
            hsdjhsdssdhj jshdsjhjsh hjsdhdjsdhjshjdhjdshdjssdhjdhsjdshjsdd
            jhjshdhjdsdhjsdhj
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="input"><input type="text" /></div>
      <div class="error">
            Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong
            errorLong errorLong error Long error Long errorLong errorLong
            jhsdhsjdhsjdh
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Label</div>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="input"><input type="text" /></div>
      <div class="error">Short error</div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set the number of columns in the css, it can totally depend on makup that user provides and antd grid (.ant-row, .ant-col) is usually used for its customization. I improved the code in example to have a full view.

Answer (score 0):

you could use that site for grid helper: for more https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/

```css
    
    body {
        padding: 50px;
        font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .form {
        display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    /* for more https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/ */
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .form {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
        }
    }

    .error {
        color: red;
        padding: 5px 0
    }

    .form-item {
        border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
        display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    
    }

    .label {
        background: orange;
    }

    .control {
        background: #eee;
        padding: 10px;
    
    }
```

```html
    <form class="form ">
        <div class="form-item">
        <div class="label">
            <div>Label </div>
            <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong instructions Long instructions Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong instructions Long instruction </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
            <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong er</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
        <div class="label">Label</div>
        <div class="control">
            <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
            <div class="error">Short error</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    </form>
```

alternative solution are:

1. you can give line-clamp for texts.
2. for text div: height:100px; overflow-y:auto;

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot set the number of columns in the css, it can totally depend on makup that user provides and antd grid is usually used for its customization. I improved the code in example to have a full view. Regarding the `line-clamp` we reviewed such solution with a team and decided to look for better one.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 500px;
}

.ant-row-tbl {
  display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr); /* Creates a flexible number of columns */
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; /* Creates two rows, auto-sized */
  column-gap: 6px; /* Vertical gap between columns */
  row-gap: 0;  /* no gap between rows */
}

/* Assuming .ant-col is a shared class for label and control */
.ant-col {
  /* Styling for both label and control */
  padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Padding included in the width */
  
}

.ant-form-item-label {
  background: orange;
  grid-row: 1; /* Place label in the first row */
}

.ant-form-item-control {
  background: #eee;
  grid-row: 2; /* Place control in the second row */
}

/* Assuming .ant-col is a shared class for label and control */

.ant-col {
  /* Styling for both label and control */
  padding: 10px;
  /* Adjust padding as needed */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Padding included in the width */
}

.ant-form-item-label {
  background: orange;
  grid-row: 1;
  /* Place label in the first row */
}

.ant-form-item-control {
  background: #eee;
  grid-row: 2;
  /* Place control in the second row */
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
  <div class="ant-form ant-form-vertical ant-form-align-fields-bottom">
<div class="ant-row-tbl">
  <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
    <div>Label </div>
    <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong<br /><br />instructionsLong </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
    <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
    <div>Label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
    <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="error">Short instructions</div>
  </div>
 <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
    <div>Label3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
    <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
    <div class="error">Short rrrr</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot set the number of columns in the css and remove antd rows and cols styles, it can totally depend on makup that user provides into form component. Usually it is antd grid that supports the responsible design with different columns count for each breakpoint.

Comment: @AlinaAndrieieva I have updated my answer, now it supports dynamic number of columns. Will this work? What other adjustments do you need?

Comment: Thanks for your work. Unfortunately I don't control the grid markup that user provides into my Form Component, so cannot manually set up the dynamic number columns, and override the responsive styles for ant-cols ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8 that are responsible for the columns width (user provides it for his form makup).

Comment: @Ke1sy NP. It is strange that you do not control the html, but do control the css. Anyway, it is 100% impossible to synchronize the height of 2 divs inside separate elements using CSS. This can be done with Javascript, do you control the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a tooltip for `:hover`?

changes marked with comments. as always :3

---

### UPD 18.01.2024

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
}

/* changes start */
.ant-form{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.ant-form-item-control{position: relative;}
.input{margin-bottom: 2.3em;}
.error {
  color: red;
  padding: 3px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1.1em;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px double red;
  border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.error:hover {
  height: auto;
}
/* changes end */

.ant-form-item {
  border: 5px solid #6f2961;
}

.ant-form-item-label {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

.ant-form-item-control {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ant-form-align-fields-bottom .ant-form-item {
  height: 100%;
}

.ant-form-align-fields-bottom .ant-form-item .ant-form-item-row {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.ant-form-align-fields-bottom .ant-form-item .ant-form-item-row .ant-form-item-control {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.24.15/antd.compact.min.css'>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ant-form ant-form-vertical ant-form-align-fields-bottom">
    <div class="ant-row">
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
              <div>Label </div>
              <div style="color: grey">Long instructionsLong instructionsLong instructionsLong </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Long error Long error Long errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong errorLong error</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ant-col ant-col-xs-24 ant-col-sm-12 ant-col-lg-8">
        <div class="ant-form-item ant-form-item-with-help">
          <div class="ant-row ant-form-item-row">
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">Label</div>
            <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control control">
              <div class="input"><input type="text"></div>
              <div class="error">Short instructions</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but we try to avoid jumping markup for our form

Comment: @Ke1sy try now :3